# unable to add two jar files in teradata udf

Tags: java, t-sql, teradata, user-defined-functions

Due to some restriction in Teradata UDF, I develop few functions as a procedures. And I develop a java program, which execute Teradata procedures and returns outputs using eclipse. Its worked perfectly. For this java program, I added two jar files (terajdbc.jar,tdgssconfig.jar) and I converted these two jar files into one jar and I added that single jar into eclipse, and it worked. I got the expected output in eclipse(using java jdbc).

Now, How can I execute the inside Teradata UDF?

can any one help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do deploy Jar and create function like

```
REPLACE FUNCTION func
  (inputStr VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET LATIN) 
 RETURNS VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET LATIN 
 SPECIFIC encryptVarchar 
 LANGUAGE JAVA 
 NO SQL
 NO EXTERNAL DATA
 PARAMETER STYLE JAVA 
 DETERMINISTIC 
 RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT 
 EXTERNAL NAME 'jarid:com.comppany.javafunction(java.lang.String) returns java.lang.String'
```